# Crop top of image responsive web design

Tags: image, css, responsive-design

I would like to display full width image in wide format (crop top of image to max-height: 500px;) on desktop display and original aspect ratio for mobile devices.

I am using gantry framework on a Wordpress site. I have used a css work around to force the image to display full width outside the parent boxed container.

**Example** This crops from the top except there is space pushed to the top when the image height is less than max-height?

```css
.boxed-container{
  margin:30px;
  padding: 30px;
  background:red;
}
.bg-img{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw !important;
  margin-right: -50vw !important;
  background: url(http://www.photographymad.com/files/images/rule-of-thirds-movement.jpg) no-repeat bottom;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxed-container">
  This is where the boxed content belongs.
  <div class="bg-img">
    <h1>This is the header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you phrase what your goal is a bit more clearly?

Comment: did you see my answer???

Comment: Yes I did see your answer thankyou this was very helpful and worked.

Comment: Glad it worked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code crops the image the correct way with `object-fit:cover`

```
#image {
    width: 100%;;
    height: 500px;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

And with `@media` you could change the height and with however you like to, to fit the screen resolution.

Sidenote: This doesn't work in IE.

EDIT:

`object-fit:`

`fill`
The replaced content is sized to fill the element’s content box: the object’s concrete object size is the element’s used width and height.

`contain`
The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while fitting within the element’s content box: its concrete object size is resolved as a contain constraint against the element’s used width and height.

`cover`
The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while filling the element’s entire content box: its concrete object size is resolved as a cover constraint against the element’s used width and height.

`none`
The replaced content is not resized to fit inside the element’s content box: the object’s concrete object size is determined using the default sizing algorithm with no specified size, and a default object size equal to the replaced element’s used width and height.

`scale-down`
The content is sized as if none or contain were specified, whichever would result in a smaller concrete object size.